# Calculating the standard deviation of a circular quantity

Tags: algorithms, standard-deviation, error-propagation

This is partially an algorithm question, but I think it is best asked in this stackexchange.

I need to find the standard deviation of an angle bounded on the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$. Taking the mean if such a quantity is usually done by converting the angles to points on the unit circle, taking the mean of those the x and y values of those points and converting the mean of x and y back into an angle. I don't think it's as straight-forward to make such a conversion with the standard deviation. My idea was to get the standard deviation of the points on the circle and convert the standard deviations in x and y to an angle using this [classic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Simplification) for error propagation where

$f(x, y) = \arctan{\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}$

There seems to be a scipy function that is designed to do this, `scipy.stats.circstd()`. The problem is my implementation gives a very different result than the scipy function, and my result gives an answer closer to what I would expect for the physical situation I am applying it to. Additionally, I do not understand what the scipy function is doing. It's source code starts on line 2773 [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/morestats.py).

What is happening in their algorithm? What is the proper way to do this?

EDIT: This is data generated from a simulation, and I don't know the underlying distribution of the angles.

Comment: The scipy algorithm does the following:

Comment: (whoops, pressed enter too soon)
1. Scales your sample angles into the range [0, 2*pi].
2. Converts each sample angle into a point on the unit circle.
3. Finds the mean of those points.
4. Computes the norm of that mean point, call it r.
5. Computes sqrt(log(1 / r^2)).
6. Scales this value back to the original range of samples, [low, high].
This doesn't completely answer your question, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: Why would sqrt(log(1/(r^2))) be what they are calculating?

Comment: Consider that the usual standard-deviation "formula" is really [just an unbiased estimator](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/192) of the parameter $\sigma$ for a normal distribution that you assume your data is sampled from. I imagine that the scipy formula comes from the same notion, applied to the [wrapped normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_normal_distribution). But best would be to ask [the guy](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/26587570-formula-used-for-the-circular-standard-deviation-is-incorrect) who seems to have wrote it! haha

Comment: In the [moments section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_normal_distribution#Moments) of the wrapped normal distribution article they actually seem to state the exact equation. And in the [estimation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_normal_distribution#Estimation_of_parameters) section, they essentially prove it. The difficult thing to *wrap* your head around (no pun intended), is the wrapped normal distribution itself. Perhaps one way to interpret it is simply as a distribution of phasors $e^{j\theta_i}$ on $\mathbb{SO2}$ instead of vectors on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Darn, at this point I feel like constructing a full answer to your question... avast, what starts in the comments stays in the comments. Upvoted your question because it made me think about interesting things

Comment: Ahhh! That makes sense. Thank you for an answer! If you wrote up an answer I'd mark it as right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Scipy's algorithm does the following:

1. Uniformly scales your sample angles into the range $[0, 2\pi]$
2. Converts each sample angle into a "point" on the unit circle
3. Finds the mean of those points
4. Computes the norm of that mean point, call it r
5. Computes $\sqrt{\log(1 / r^2)}$
6. Scales this value back to the original range of the samples

All the steps seem reasonable except maybe #5. Where does that formula come from? Well first we need to ask the question, where does *this* formula come from?
$$\hat\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(x-\hat\mu)^2},\ \ \ \ \ \hat\mu=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$$

I write $\hat\sigma$ and $\hat\mu$ with hats because they are really estimators of the true population values of standard deviation and mean. I'll let Wikipedia do the variance [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance) for you, i.e. prove that $\mathbf{E}(\hat\sigma^2)=\sigma^2$.

Their results make use of some operators that we take for granted when our samples are from $\mathbb{R}$, like addition, subtraction, and a commutative multiplication. You have random angles though, which live on $\mathbb{SO2}$ and so we cannot be so care-free.

Rather than trying to guess an estimator of variance for random variables on $\mathbb{SO2}$, we can take an alternative perspective. The normal distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ is special for many reasons, but one is that its variance is exactly one of the two parameters that defines its probability density function (pdf),
$$\rho(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

We can "wrap" this pdf around the unit circle as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_distribution) by stacking up the density at $x$ with the density at $x+2\pi k,\ \ \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$. Once we do this, we must limit our sample-space to $[0, 2\pi]$ (or any interval of length $2\pi$) or else we won't be satisfying the definition of a pdf: that its integral over the whole sample-space is 1. Make sure you shift your samples into this range before you use a wrapped pdf!

Doing this results in the [wrapped normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_normal_distribution); call its probability measure $P_o$ and its density $\rho_o$. Perhaps its variance can give us some insight to what a good "circular variance" estimator would look like. To compute the variance, we can't make use of the expectation over $\mathbb{R}$ like we usually do,
$$\mathbf{E}(X) \neq \int_{0}^{\infty}x\rho_o(x)dx$$
for the reason I stated a moment ago. We'll take our samples as the unit phasors (unit-magnitude complex numbers), a valid representation of $\mathbb{SO2}$ complete over the real domain $[0, 2\pi]$.
$$\mathbf{E}(X) = \int_{\mathbb{SO2}}x\ dP_o = \int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{j\theta}\rho_o(\theta)d\theta$$

This is what is done [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_normal_distribution#Moments) where they are able to compute the nth moment and then yank out an expression for $\sigma$ from it, that looks much like the scipy equation. In my description of the scipy algorithm, I put the word "point" in quotes because they are really treating your samples as unit phasors, not vectors. In the [next section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_normal_distribution#Moments) of the Wikipedia article, they find an (albeit biased) estimator of this $\sigma$ which is exactly what scipy computes.

I would say that this method is "correct" in that it isn't ad-hoc. If you find that your estimator makes more sense for your application, perhaps it is really what you want, but I would consider the scipy function to be the "right" way to measure spread of angles.

Answer (score 0):

A random angle is defined as $X_2-X_1$ with $X_1$ and $X_2$ independent, uniform random variables on $(-\pi,\pi]$. Therefore:

$$Var(X_2-X_1)=Var(X_1)+(-1)^2Var(X_2)$$

$$=2Var(X_1)=2 \dfrac{1}{12}(2 \pi)^2=\dfrac23 \pi^2$$

Reference:(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous))

Taking the square root:

$$\sigma=\sqrt{\dfrac23} \pi$$

Comment: This is informative, but I don't know the underlying distribution of the angles. The angles are data generated from a simulation, and I'm looking to characterize the spread of their values. I wasn't terribly clear about this though.